# Object Publication and Escape Java concurrency , how does this reference exactly escapes here?

Tags: java, object, concurrency, safe-publication

I was recently going through "Java Concurrency in practice" and came across example of Publication and Escape , after going through it several times I still feel that I didn't completely understood the example.

[image: Content owner specification]

```
public class ThisEscape{
       public ThisEscape(EventSource source){
            source.registerListener(
              new EventListener(){
                 public void onEvent(Event e){
                   doSomething(e);
                 }
              }
            )
       }
}
```

> ThisEscape illustrates an important special case of Escape - when the *this* references escapes during construction. When the inner EvenListener instance is publised ,so is the enclosing ThisEsape instance.But and object is in a predictable ,consistent state only after its constructuor return. so publishing an object from within its constructor can publish an incompletely constructed object.This is true even if the publication is the last statement in the constructor.If the this reference escapes during construction, the object is considered not properly constructed.

`ThisEscape` cosntructor is registering a EventSource with and EventListener where we are specifying an onEvent behaviour passing an Event instance.
But here I assume the order of object construction to be `EventListener --> ThisEscape` so how the *this* reference of `ThisEscape` is being passed here to escape ?

Comment: Is `doSomething` a method of `ThisEscape`?

Comment: That I also really not sure about as the code is an excerpt but most probably it would be a method of EventListener as while EventListener construction we are specifying the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I believe we should refer to this excerpt:

> When the inner EvenListener instance is published, so is the enclosing ThisEsape instance.

Which makes me think `doSomething()` is a method of `ThisEscape` (otherwise the reference would not escape), meaning `ThisEscape` is a listener for `EventSource`, and it registers itself during construction via overriding `EventListener`'s `onEvent` method.

In simple words, it says: "when a new event occurs, call `doSomething()`".

At this point the problem is quite simple. Imagine it, we've registered a new listener inside `ThisEscape`'s constructor... and immediately... an event occurs! While one thread is still constructing `ThisEscape`, another one is already calling `doSomething()`, which may lead to a very unpredictable result...

Answer (score 0):

Actually it requires registering events after completing initialisation of objects (after construction)
so it recommends
use private construction

```
private SafeListener(){
  listener = new EventListener(){
     public void onEvent(Event e){
       doSomething(e);
     } 
  };
}

public static SafeListener newInstance(EventSource source){
   SafeListener safe = new SafeListener();
   source.registerListener(safe.listener);
   return safe;
}
```

this one is much safer.